# Installation fails with "error: No such disk" 

Tags: 11.04, installation, server, grub2

I installed ubuntu 11.04 with the CD. My computer already has windows 7, and I want to install Ubuntu, the installation process takes place normally, I used to be ubuntu, but when my windows 7 to escape and use it on ubuntu then an error occurs is:

```
error: No such device 00000000 0000000000000 -------- ----- --------- 000,000 000,000
error: No such disk
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

Press any key to continue ....

I had to reinstall ubuntu again, but the results remain like that.
Who can show me how to fix on it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean ubuntu 11.04? There's no such thing as ubuntu 4.11.

Comment: sr i'm error my title: ubuntu server 11.04. Thanks

Comment: Please add more details as to whether it was a Wubi install or a side-by-side install.

Answer (score 1):

Please reinstall grub booting from the live install cd ... select try Ubuntu without install and follow this page:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2?action=show&redirect=GRUB2#Reinstalling_GRUB2
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: I fixed it by Reinstalling Grub. Thanks marcobra